# Is there a way to sort a collection when creating random documents inside a collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to use orderBy( ) when creating random documents inside a collection such that the newly created one will always come after the previous one.

In my case the collection is called ‘Chats’ and documents are created at random and I loop through them to reveal messages. I want an order where newly created documents will always come after the previous ones. how do I achieve this?

```
firestore
    .collection(InterviewsInformation)
    .document(InterviewID)
    .collection('Chat')
    .add({
  'MessageSender': MessageSender,
  'MessageText': messageText,
});
```

I also tried sorting the collection by using a timestamp

```
firestore
    .collection(InterviewsInformation)
    .document(InterviewID)
    .collection('Chat')
    .add({
  'MessageSender': employer['EmployerName'],
  'MessageText': messageText,
  'CreatedAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
firestore
    .collection(InterviewsInformation)
    .document(InterviewID)
    .collection('Chat').orderBy("CreatedAt", descending: true) ;
```

still doesn't work messages appear at random, can someone help?

Comment: Adding a timestamp should work, and is your best option.  What exactly does it do that's different than what you expect?

Comment: It's creating documents at random instead of giving them an order

Comment: A query using the timestamp field should provide them in order.  They won't naturally appear ordered in the console, if that's what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that documents wont be created by random in the cloud firestore but your query in the stream builder can help show them in a sorted order

```
stream: firestore
          .collection(InterviewsInformation)
          .document(InterviewID)
          .collection('Chat').orderBy('CreatedAt')
          .snapshots(),
```